# Firefox: How does overflow work with z-index and position fixed?

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, position, z-index

I am confused about how the CSS for z-index, overflow hidden, and position fixed work together in Firefox 3.6.  Consider this example:

The first `DIV.fix_z0` is position fixed with z-index 0 and overflow hidden.  Inside is  `DIV.abs_z1` with position absolute with z-index 1.  Inside that is `DIV.fix_z2` with position fixed and z-index 2.  I would expect all of `.fix_z2` to be visible even if it is outside the viewport of `.fix_z0` since it is both fixed and has a higher z-index than the base DIV.

In IE 8 this works as expected, but in FF 3.6, `DIV.fix_z2` is clipped by the bounds of `.fix_z0`.  Both elements are fixed, but one is nested within the other.  W3C specs indicate that fixed elements should be removed from document flow, but what happens when they are nested?  Also, since the containing element `.abs_z1` has a higher z-index, this should set up a new z-index context and everything in `.abs_z1` should be above `.fix_z0` (making the z-index on `.fix_z2` irrelevant, but I included it to see if it made a difference.)

The complicating factor is the z-index.  If we take an alternate example, inside `.fix_z0` a `DIV.abs_znone` with position absolute and no z-index.  Inside this, we place `DIV.fix_z1` with position fixed and z-index 1.  Now the `DIV.fix_z1` is not clipped by `.fix_z0`.  It seems to me that either both should be clipped or both should not be clipped.  Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the rules of CSS?  Below is the code to reproduce.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Z-Index Woes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }

    div.fix_z0 {
        position: fixed;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
        bottom: 100px;
        right: 100px;
        background-color: #606060;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    div.abs_z1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #550000;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    div.fix_z2 {
        position: fixed;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #888800;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    div.abs_znone {
        position: absolute;
        right: 50px;
        bottom: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #005500;
    }


    div.fix_z1 {
        position: fixed;
        right: 50px;
        bottom: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #888800;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    p {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #EFEFEF;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    p.center {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    p.right {
        right: 0;
    }

    p.bottom {
        bottom: 0;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fix_z0">
        <p class="center">pos: fixed, z:0, overflow: hidden</p>
        <div class="abs_z1">
            <p class="right">pos: abs, z:1</p>
            <div class="fix_z2">
                <p class="right bottom">pos: fix, z:2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="abs_znone">
            <p>pos: abs, z: none</p>
            <div class="fix_z1">
                <p>pos: fix, z:1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 11/18/10**: 
Both responses thus far seem to indicate that `.fix_z2` and `.fix_z1` should be clipped by `.fix_z0`.  This would make IE8 100% wrong and FF 50% wrong on the sample code.

I would argue that both DIVs should NOT be clipped since they are fixed.  W3C establishes fixed positioning as a subset of absolute and an absolutely positioned element:

> establishes a new containing block for normal flow children and absolutely (**but not fixed**) positioned descendants. [[W3C]](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning)

Therefore, it seems to me that neither `.fix_z0` or `.abs_z1` or `.abs_znone` should establish a new containing block by which the fixed contents are clipped.

The W3C Z-Index standard values are:

> **integer:** This integer is the stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context. The box also establishes a local stacking context in which its stack level is '0'.
>
> **auto:** The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is the same as its parent's box. The box does not establish a new local stacking context.
>
> *http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index*

I don't see why z-index affects FF, but it has the following effect:  Since `.abs_znone` has no z-index, it has the same stacking context as its parent `.fix_z0` and `.fix_z1` would have a z-index in relation to any children of `.fix_z0`.  The result is `DIV.fix_z1` is NOT clipped by `.fix_z0`.  Conversely, `.abs_z1` establishes a new stacking context since it has a z-index and `.fix_z2` would have a z-index in relation to any children of `.abs_z1` but for some reason, this results in `.fix_z2` being clipped by `.fix_z0`

Bottom line: I am still looking for some answers.  Is IE or FF adhering to standards here?  What is causing clipping on one DIV in FF but not the other?  My current take is that IE is correct (for a change) and that the FF behavior is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the FF display is correct.  If you have overflow:hidden on an element all child elements will only be displayed if they are in the bounds of the parent objects.

Comment: I agree with your logic, but if this were true then fix_z1 should also be clipped since it is a descendant of fix_z0.  Instead it is not clipped.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957084/ie8-xhtml-position-fixed-and-z-index), and one of the answerers gave [this link](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) to solve, but that was for IE7.  I tried the doctype suggestion, but it didn't yield any immediate results.

(BTW, in your code example, if you give `.abs_znone` a z-index, that ties it to its parent and it behaves properly.  A clue, perhaps?)

Comment: These issues did deal with z-index, but differently from my case.  They are more about layering and my issue is with clipping.  In my case, IE is actually doing what I want and FF is not, therefore I am not looking to "fix" anything with IE.  The z-index seems to be having some clipping side-effects in FF and I have some disagreement with the current posts about whether the IE behavior is standards-compliant or not.  See my update in the question.